# Sanctions regarding Neymar transfer from Santos to Barcelona

Tags: rules, football, transfer

I was just reading a breakdown of the Neymar transfer and it all seems very suspect and complicated especially considering how [Rossell has now resigned](http://www.theguardian.com/football/2014/jan/23/sandro-rosell-resigns-barcelona-president-neymar). Does anyone know what sanctions can now be brought against Rossell or any of the other parties involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Barcelona have been charged with tax fraud](http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/european/neymar-cleared-of-fraud-barcelona-transfer-investigation-corruption-trial-a7719031.html) over the Neymar transfer by a Spanish court and there could be further charges of misappropriation of funds brought against them.